# Next.js: How can I use tsParticles with Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tsparticles

I am trying to use [tsParticles](https://particles.js.org/) within my Next.js project but I can not seem to find a proper documentation for using it with React or Next.js.

I already tried various sources, searching on youtube google and possibly anywhere II happen to have access.

Comment: After [looking into the library](https://particles.js.org/) I have notices that it is obviously pretty heavy on client side code. You can create a [client component](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/client-components) to wrap the components and logic of this library.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for using tsParticles with React can be found [here](https://github.com/tsparticles/react?tab=readme-ov-file#installation).